# how to use $.startajax and $.closeajax for showing a loading panel during a ajax call

Tags: jquery

Hello all I want to use $.ajaxstart() and $.ajaxcomplete() for  showing  a loading panel during a ajax call
can anyonyone give me a piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide very little information, so I just try to give you another way to deal with it by using the `beforeSend` and `done` events to handle your request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "demo.html",
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
       // Make your init action of the progress
  }
}).done(function ( data ) {
      // End action of the progress
});
```

You can find out anything in the jQuery-Documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and here http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/